# Check if 2 objects from an array overlap and change their position on y if they do

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So how can I update the position every time I call the StartRandomizingRightSpikePosition

```
private bool CheckOverlap(GameObject o1, GameObject o2)
{
  return spikeRight.Select(t => t.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.Intersects(t.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds)).FirstOrDefault();
}

public void StartRandomizingRightSpikesPosition()
{
  foreach (var t in spikeRight)
  {
    foreach (var t1 in spikeRight)
    {
      if (t == t1) continue;
      if (!CheckOverlap(t, t1)) continue;
      yPosition = Random.Range(-7, 7);
      var position = t1.transform.position;
      desiredPosition = new Vector3(position.x, yPosition, position.z);
      t1.transform.position = desiredPosition;

      Debug.Log(t.gameObject + " intersects " + t1.gameObject);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes but I'm not sure you would want too.  I'm not sure you're going to find a way to do this efficiently and you might be better off finding a way to generate the objects such that this step is not necessary.

I can't tell from your question how the objects are actually stored so I'm going to provide some sample code that just deals with a simple array of Rectangles. You should be able to adapt it to your specifics.

I tried to make it slightly more efficient by not checking both t1 == t and t == t1.

```
    const int Bounds = 1000;

    static bool RemovedOverlappingRects(Rectangle[] rects)
    {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < rects.Length; ++pos)
        {
            for (int check = pos +1; check < rects.Length; ++check)
            {
                var r1 = rects[pos];
                var r2 = rects[check];

                if (r1.IntersectsWith(r2))
                {
                    r2.Y = Rng.Next(1, Bounds);
                    rects[check] = r2;

                    Console.WriteLine($"{pos} overlaps with {check}");

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Once we've randomly generated a new rectangle we have to start over.  Which means invoking the above method in a loop.

```
            var rects = GetRandomeRects(20).ToArray();

            while (RemovedOverlappingRects(rects))
                ;
```

Because of the random movement I'm not certain you can guarantee this will always end.  If you can deal with the non-random look of the results changing it to stack the overlaps would I believe always finish.  That would be this:

```
r2.Y = r1.Y + r1.Height + 1;
```

in place of

```
r2.Y = Rng.Next(1, Bounds);
```

But even then you're still dealing with a very unpredictable run time due to the random input.

Maybe someone else can show us a more efficient way...

Comment: There was another way but eventually I fixed it instead of randomizing the position of the objects and checking the collision I randomized the actual array and then I moved the first three indexes.